# Create HTML element on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a new HTML element when the users scrolls more than 50px, but the problem is that the condition is too broad and the element gets created multiple times, at every pixel above 50px.

How can I make this more specific to avoid this and only create the element once?

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#subnav-cont').prepend('<div id="mm-logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" /></div>');
      } else {
        $('#mm-logo').remove();
      }
    });
```

Comment: `=== 50` seems like the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a flag e.g `created_flag` to avoid multiple creation :

```
var created_flag = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50 && !created_flag) {
        $('#subnav-cont').prepend('<div id="mm-logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" /></div>');
        created_flag=true;
    } else {
        $('#mm-logo').remove();
        created_flag=false;
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** As of jQuery 3.0, `.bind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()`, so use it instead.

Hoep this helps.